# uiscrollview not scroll smoothly in iphone 4

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I have implemented [TMQuiltView](https://github.com/1000Memories/TMQuiltView/archive/master.zip).

It work fine in iPhone 5 and iOS 5 and iOS 6.0 also. I have my iPhone 4. Its updates to iOS 6. but scroll is not smoothly. whats problem there? can any one help me please.

Comment: Are you loading images in your scroll view?

Comment: yes, but i am using lazy loading to load images only problem in iPhone4 in other device its works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to say without seeing your code and monitoring the performance on a device.

However, I suggest you use [Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH1-SW1), in particular the Core Animation instrument to measure your app’s graphical performance on your iPhone 4.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the device is not powerful enough to handle all the operations quickly enough to make the view scroll smoothly.

Without any code example it's hard to say if you are able to improve the performance without digging into the library itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have handle many imageVews in your scrollViews delegate , you can run the `instrument` , choose the "time" and to look at the time every method costs . when your method costs more than 1000ms/24 , maybe you should modify the method